# Post PHP8.1 PhpMyAdmin 5.1.4 Upgrade Landing Page Blank AFTER Login

Tags: mysql, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 server with Virtualmin, LAMP. (php8.1).  I upgraded my PhpMyAdmin install from 4.9.5  to 5.1.4.   I can successfully login, however my landing page and left-hand panel are bank:

[image]

**Question**

How should I go about fixing the problem?

**Additional Info:**
I checked my Apache Error Logs and I found:

```
[Thu Oct 06 10:03:47.438807 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2782541:tid 140246271289088] [client 123.456.789.12:36274] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
[Thu Oct 06 10:02:27.804468 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2782541:tid 140246271289088] [client 123.456.789.12:57554] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
[Thu Oct 06 10:02:27.744775 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2782541:tid 140246380394240] [client 123.456.789.12:57554] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
[Thu Oct 06 10:02:27.661524 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2782541:tid 140246271289088] [client 123.456.789.12:57554] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
[Thu Oct 06 10:02:27.580285 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2782541:tid 140246506284800] [client 123.456.789.12:57554] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
```

**Doesn't Make Sense:**

```
:/backups/incremental-backups# stat /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php
  File: /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php
  Size: 68          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 139000      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2022-10-06 09:59:17.437482274 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-03 20:21:17.706858621 +0800
Change: 2022-05-03 20:21:17.706858621 +0800
 Birth: -

# stat /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
  File: /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
  Size: 535         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 270333      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2022-10-06 09:59:17.365481061 +0800
Modify: 2022-04-16 09:28:20.000000000 +0800
Change: 2022-05-08 15:30:57.781777180 +0800
 Birth: -
```

www-data does have access

```
# stat phpmyadmin
  File: phpmyadmin
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 264469      Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-10-06 09:59:20.465533315 +0800
Modify: 2022-10-06 09:59:16.861472565 +0800
Change: 2022-10-06 09:59:16.861472565 +0800
 Birth: -
root@admin:/etc# ls -la phpmyadmin
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      4096 Oct  6 09:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 190 root root     12288 Oct  4 22:55 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       755 May 15 06:25 apache.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      4096 Apr  1  2020 conf.d
-rw-r-----   1 root www-data   535 Apr 16 09:28 config-db.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       168 Apr 16 09:28 config.footer.inc.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       168 Apr 16 09:28 config.header.inc.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      6340 May  8 16:17 config.inc.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      6018 May 20 06:50 config.inc.php.dpkg-dist
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       273 Apr 16 09:28 lighttpd.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       198 Apr 16 09:28 phpmyadmin.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       295 Apr 16 09:28 phpmyadmin.service
```